# create user segment for device specific and assign the content item in Endeca

Tags: endeca

In endeca I want to show specific Content Item to specific User.
Meanse If the User Is Logged In user I want to show Some Products/Banners/slots.
if The User Is annonymous User(NOT LOGGED in USer)Then I want to show Some Other Pages.in atg we can find out the user type by profile  but in endeca How Can I do this,and How Can i create the User Segments for the Both Users in Endeca experience Manager or in endeca work Bench?any scenario is exist?and how to find user is logged from which type of device(desktop or tablet)?(create user segment for device specific and assign the content item  in Endeca)?can any one Help me For this Task?

Thank You,
Sudeer.

Comment: Are you using ATG and Endeca?

Comment: in endeca work bench we have to define different pages for both registered user and anonymous users. based on the type we have to show the content item.

Comment: in ATG how to do also I don't know ,if you have any idea in atg or endeca or both please share withy me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating an Anonymous User Segment in BCC and using it in Endeca Experience Manager.

The overall steps are as follows:

1) Go into BCC and create a User Segment called Anonymous.  The rule for this User Segment should be "People whose Security Status is ANONYMOUS".  To create a LoggedIn User Segment the rule should be "People whose Security Status is not ANONYMOUS".

2) Deploy your BCC project.

3) In Endeca Experience Manager in the User Segments section, create a User Segment with the same name ("Anonymous" or "LoggedIn")

4) Now you should be able to utilize the BCC User Segment you created previously, in Endeca slots.

A good link that explains these steps with screenshots and in more detail is here:

https://endecaworld.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/user-segments-in-atg-endeca-integration/