# How to do segmentation in endeca for a specific user (registered user and anonymous user)

Tags: endeca

How can we show the specific content the user based on their status i.e logged in user are not logged in user(anonymous user) and based on that we have to show the specific content that is configured in endeca work bench.and one more thing in this task is that to it has to consider another parameter that user is sending the request from which device(tablet or desktop or loptap or mobile)?

How can we do this ?

Please help me!

Thank You!

Comment: possible duplicate of [create user segment for device specific and assign the content item in Endeca](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698920/create-user-segment-for-device-specific-and-assign-the-content-item-in-endeca)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'user segments' for this type of functionality. It will require that you send the segment as a parameter with your query. However, you may have issues with multiple segments as the system will require all to trigger not 'one of'.

A better solution would be a generic dimension which can be applied to your entire data set and then be used as a trigger without effecting the results, since implicit selection does not trigger exp manager rules.

Good Luck