# How can we create the Page In endeca workbench for Registered User and anonymous User

Tags: endeca

How can we create pages in endeca workbench based on User Profile(that may be registered user OR anonymous User),and assing the Content Item To the Based On Their People.Please Can any one Provide The Information regarding this .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do segmentation in endeca for a specific user (registered user and anonymous user)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715167/how-to-do-segmentation-in-endeca-for-a-specific-user-registered-user-and-anonym)

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Please refrain from asking the same question repeatedly. Perhaps if you add more detail to one of the questions you've already asked on this topic (for example what have you tried), you'll have more luck getting some help.